# python pip ask me to update but it is already updated

Tags: python, pip

Every time I use pip to install some package, it says:

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

But when I run 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
It says:
Requirement already up-to-date:
Why is this happening?

Comment: Is pip linked to python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Holloway How should I know that?

Comment: `pip --version` should tell you.  Mine has `pip 18.1 from /path/to/pip (python 2.7)`. Are you on windows/linux/mac?

Comment: Im on windows. It says: pip 10.0.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, `pip` is linked to your python 3 installation. The version of `pip` included in your python 2 installation is up to date (as shown by the `python -m ...` command you ran).

To update pip for python3, run the same command but using `python3` instead. Something like

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Given that the pip you are using is saying it needs updating, you could also just run

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I get this error: 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: Ok. I'm not familiar with Windows or anaconda. What command do you use to run python scripts?

Comment: I just type name of python file in windows cmd. like program.py and it runs. in linux we type ./program.py in terminal.